# Why Axios doesn't return data

Tags: javascript, axios, redux-thunk

I have found questions on this topic, but the answers do not work. I need your help to understand. I try to get data from the server with axios. Where is my mistake?

```
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_DATA_CUSTOMERS:
      return {
        ...state,
        data: action.data
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export function getCustomersData() {
  const url = 'someUrl'
  return (dispatch) => {
    axios.get(url)
      .then(res => dispatch({
        type: GET_DATA_CUSTOMERS,
        data: res.data
      }))
      .catch(res => dispatch({
        type: GET_CUSTOMER_ERROR,
        error: res.error
      }))
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey and welcome to SO ! What does the server return ? Axios must log at least "something"

Comment: Please provide more information (which url do you use, is server on this url started, etc)

Comment: Also you can try to open console (F12). What do you see there?

Comment: If you can't/don't know how to use a debugger add console logs in your .then() .catch() functions and check if there is an error there. Then please provide more info about your problem

Comment: thank all of you very much. I solved my problem by restarting the server. I don't know what it was, but the response returns as a catch case - with type GET_CUSTOMER_ERROR in Redux Dev Tools. It will be interesting to understand why it happened